# How to find letters in a string that contains mostly numbers in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a field that is a string but should be mostly numbers. I need to be able to find if a letter is in this string. The letter can be in any spot in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where regexp_like(field, '[^0-9]');
```

That is, return any row where `field` has a non-digit.